# How to Install LDOM on Solaris 11?

Tags: virtualbox, solaris

I installed Solaris 11 on VirtualBox. I need to install and configure `LDOM`. However, I can not find the `LDOM` software for oracle Solaris 11. I could not find the link also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LDOM is the Sun/Oracle hypervisor layer for SPARC machines, and so only works on SPARC hardware (v9 or higher).  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_VM_Server_for_SPARC

You can't run this inside VirtualBox.  VirtualBox doesn't emulate SPARC hardware, it's an Intel/AMD virtualisation technology.

However you should be able to run Solaris Zones inside your Solaris 11 install; these are closer to containers and so run inside the single kernel.

Comment: how can i switch domains in ldom ? If i have 3 different domain dom1, dom2, dom 3. How can i switch between domains.

Comment: Sounds like that should be asked as a new question...